# Is there a way to install APK on the lastest Samsung Smart TV? (2016, KU Series)

Tags: apk, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I wanted to install some APK file on my **Samsung TV (UE55KU6400UXZF)**

I'm not even sure OS is Tizen but it seems so. Does anyone know a way to install APK on it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I had to use Tizen Studio and create a native app.

http://developer.samsung.com/tv